# How to get specific columns from different tables ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I Want to get some specific column from two tables different ChatMessage And ChatGroup.
So that after returning data only contain messageId,  Message, SenderUserId, CreatedDate, ChatGroupId.

The query returns all the information of the ApplicationUser and ChatGroup data including the email , hashed Password, user1, user2, again **ChatMessages** and many more I don't want. So I tried by adding `Select` in implementation.

A error occur will Implementing this.

Implementation :

```
public  IEnumerable<ChatMessage> GetMessageInChat(ChatModel model)
{
    try
    {
        PutReadZero(model).Wait();
        return _context.ChatMessages.Where(userID => userID.ChatGroup.Id == model.GroupId)
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Reverse()
            .Select(p => new 
            {
                p.Id,
                p.Message,
                SenderUserId= p.SenderUser.Id,
                p.CreatedDate,
                ChatGroupId = p.ChatGroup.Id,
            })
            .ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

ChatMessage.cs :

```
namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class ChatMessage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser SenderUser { get; set; }
        public ChatGroup ChatGroup { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ChatGroup :

```
namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class ChatGroup
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User2 { get; set; }
        public int User1Unread { get; set; }
        public int User2Unread { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<ChatMessage> ChatMessages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ChatModel.cs :

```
namespace ProjectName
{
    public class ChatModel
    {
        public string SenderId { get; set; }
        public string ReceiverId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public IFormFile FileContent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Error :**

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, string Message, string SenderUserId, System.DateTime CreatedDate, int ChatGroupId>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.ChatMessage>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Remove AsEnumerable, and correct Select to return ChatMessage

Answer (score 1):

You can use FromSqlRaw and write the select query if you want only the data of table without any joins.

```
`var data = _context.ChatMessages.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * from ChatMessages Where ChatGroupId = model.GroupId").ToList();`
```

In this way you will get all your required data

Answer (score 0):

That's because you specified your method should return an `IEnumerable<ChatMessage>` but your result is returning an anonymous type.
If this is an action method in a controller, simply return an `IActionResult` which allows any data type in its response

```
public IActionResult GetMessageInChat(ChatModel model)
{
   ... 
    var result = _context.ChatMessages.Where(userID => userID.ChatGroup.Id == model.GroupId).OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate).AsEnumerable().Reverse().Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Message, SenderUserId= p.SenderUser.Id, p.CreatedDate, ChatGroupId = p.ChatGroup.Id, }).ToList();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

If it is not, remove the `.Select(...)` from your query in the original method.

```
return _context.ChatMessages.Where(userID => userID.ChatGroup.Id == model.GroupId) .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedDate).Reverse().ToList();
```

Then do the filtering with `Select` in the action method that calls the `GetMessageInChat()`. The action method should return an `IActionResult`

Comment: The return type is `IEnumerable<ChatMessage>`, not IEnumerable<ChatModel>.

Answer (score 0):

Have a new model that only contains the properties you want.

```
public class ChatMessageViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int SenderUserId { get; set; }
    public int ChatGroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then select this model in the linq:

```
.Select(p => new ChatMessageViewModel
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Message = p.Message,
    SenderUserId= p.SenderUser.Id,
    CreatedDate  = p.CreatedDate,
    ChatGroupId = p.ChatGroup.Id,
})
```

Then change the return type to `IEnumerable<ChatMessageViewModel>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need strongly typed object from the `GetMessageInChat` method, then you should just go with the answer of @mj1313.

But if you don't need a typed object (for example, if `GetMessageInChat` is an action method in some controller class), you can simply change the method signature to return a `dynamic` type -

```
public dynamic GetMessageInChat(ChatModel model)
```

You can call the method as -

```
var myList = myObject.GetMessageInChat(chatModel);
```